# Select rows grouped by which rows end in the same 4 digits with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Not sure what this is called so that limits my ability to search for an answer.

I have a table with form submissions, each row is a single field from this form. Each group of fields (each submission) is tagged with a timestamp and an index number, such as `3247623445.8446`. Each row also has a column that states the name of the field, and then another with the value for that field.

I need to select all of this data for export, grouping all the rows that in end in the same last 4 digits, so I can preferably create an associative array as such: `$rows['8446'][fieldname] = $value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
...
GROUP BY RIGHT(yourfield, 4)
```

would do the trick, assuming those numbers are stored as strings and not floats/doubles.

Of course, on a second read of your question, I've probably got that wrong. For your grouping in PHP, it'd be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $digits = substr($row['yourfield'], -4, 4); // get rightmost 4 chars
   $rows[$digits]...
}
```